# Multiple requests to a single TCP Port Service

Tags: c#, sql, sockets, queue

I am currently working on an application that connects our users to a single instance TCP socket hosted by one of our vendors. What I am hoping to have is a web service that will then translate over to the TCP Socket.

The main issue is that the socket only allows data from one of our users to be sent at a given time. So currently if User 2 were to send a request, User 1’s session would be logged out and any further data would not be sent. This wouldn’t be a problem and I could just store the requests in a SQL table to have them go in order, except that I need the response string that the vendor sends back to know the status of the transaction.

I’ve looked at trying to use the Queue class in C#, but it doesn’t look like there is any easy way to get the response from the TCP socket back to the original caller. Just looking for advice on the best way to accomplish a waiting method (which would be very short as the socket session generally lasts less than a second) so that we wouldn’t have to worry about ever disconnecting another user’s session.

Comment: So your application has two TCP connections per user? One to the user and one to the original server? Basically a proxy server? Then just wait and hold the connection to the user until it's their turn, get the data form the original server and then send it to the user.

Comment: Correct, the only difference is that the connection from my application to the user would be a REST API, and the original server would be a TCP Socket.  I'm trying to figure out how to make it where only one at a time attempt to connect to the TCP Socket.

Comment: In doing some more research, it looks like a Mutex or Semaphore will work for what I'm trying to accomplish.  Does anyone have any insight on whether this is a good practice?